# hamburger menu looks fuzzy on non-retina screens?

Tags: css

I have the following hamburger menu

```
<div class="hamburgerMenu">
<span></span>
<span></span>
<span></span>
</div>

.hamburgerMenu {
  float: left;
  outline: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 60px;
  background: none;
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);

  &:hover {
      outline: none;
  }
}
.hamburgerMenu span {
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 1px;
  height: 2px;
  width: 24px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: black;
  margin-top: 3px;
  display: block;
  content: '';
}
```

For some reason, on non-retina screens, the menu looks really fuzzy. I'm guessing maybe the span elements are too close together. Can someone help?

Answer (score 3):

Your boundaries are at half-pixels. Change `margin-top: 3px;` to an even number like `margin-top: 4px;`, or stop using `top: 50%; transform: translateY(-50%)` to position it.

Comment: it looks better at 3px though on retina screens. would rather keep the 3px.

Comment: The `50%` is probably what's causing you to have fractional pixels.

Comment: I need it to be vertically centered